# How to create a Microsoft excel file using apple script

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

how to create excel file with name using apple script? 
In this script excel file is created but workbook name is not set.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
      make new workbook at end with properties{name:"MyIndia"}
end tell
```

Comment: You have to save a workbook before it can have a name (other than the default name)

Comment: ok, How to get a workbook name after creating the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set myWorkbook to make new workbook
    save workbook as myWorkbook filename "My Workbook Name"
end tell
```

To get a workbook's name before saving the excel file:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set myWorkbook to make new workbook
    return myWorkbook's name
end tell
```

Comment: I want ,change the name of workbook without saving a workbook file.

Comment: As Tim Williams points out, you have to save a workbook before it can have a name.

Comment: ok, How to get a workbook name before saving  the excel file.

Comment: k,Thanks , My next question is if two excel file is open , first file name is "FIRST" ans second file name is "SECOND" and my cursor selection is first file. I want ,My data insert in second file using apple script.